# SQL query in MATLAB with fetch gave me wrong date value

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I'm trying to run SQL query in Matlab with the fetch function. Everything works well except that I'm getting all the dates pushed back by 2 days. When I run the same SQL query in the MSFT SQL Server Management Studio, I get all the correct dates.

A simplified version of the query I'm running is

```
use DatabaseName

select Date
from TableName
where Date = '2016-09-02'
```

The Matlab code I use to run the query is

```
conn = database(...); % connect to the database
fid = fopen('SQLQuery.sql', 'r');
tmp.SQLQuery = fscanf(fid, '%c');
fclose(fid);
tmp.QueryResult = fetch(conn, tmp.SQLQuery);
```

What I got in Matlab is a cell array with all `'2016-08-31'`. Could anyone help point out what could possibly go wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `fread(fid, '*char')'` rather than `fscanf`? Reading it in a character at a time may be causing issues?

Comment: @Suever Tried using `fread` instead of `fscanf`, but still got the same result

Comment: Silly question: did you print the query string in MATLAB, right before calling `fetch` and verify that the date is really correct there?

Comment: @hbaderts Yes, did check that and it was correct there. And actually, if I `select` some additional columns in the SQL query, what I got was the data for the correct date, i.e. `2016-09-02`.